# Qt: making a layout's children invisible/visible

Tags: qt, user-interface, qt4, show-hide

I have a `QHBoxLayout` and I want to make its children invisible and then visible later. I've tried all kinds of combinations of `QWidget::findChildren()`, `QObject::children()` and `QLayout::widget()`, but none of these work. The first 2 return empty lists and the 2nd returns a NULL.

Comment: You need to show the code you've tried -- preferably a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The widgets aren't children of a layout: a `QWidget` can be only a child of a `QWidget`, and `QLayout` is not a widget. You must recursively enumerate the layout's elements instead. Recall that `QLayout` is-a `QLayoutItem`:

```
void setLayoutVisible(QLayoutItem *item, bool visible) {
  if (auto widget = item->widget())
    return widget->setVisible(visible);
  if (auto layout = item->layout())
    for (int i = 0; i < layout->count(); ++i)
      setLayoutVisible(layout->itemAt(i), visible);
};
```